# What is master/slave architecture when related to network bridges, and why would I use one?

Tags: networking, bridge, master

I was going through some instructional materials that show how to set up a master/slave relation on a linux virtual bridge, and while the mechanics of setting up a bridge in this way are clear, I can't understand what exactly it does.

What is the use of master and slave ports, and why do we use it?

Comment: Bridges originally sererated collision domains. In modern networking they are usually just extending a network segment.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart But what is the connection to a slave/master relationship?

Comment: I think it depends on the context. The only hierarchy I know of for bridging or switching, would be spanning tree protocol (stp). Which stops bridging/switching loops.